# Mutt fails to send email

Tags: ubuntu, email, mutt, hostname

In my Azure ci/cd pipeline, I am executing tests on Ubuntu 20.04. At the end of the test, I created task in the azure pipeline , to send an email to team with attachment of test reports.

I am using bash script in the azure task.

Here is the code:

```
echo "line1"
sudo apt install mailutils
echo "line2"
sudo apt install mutt

echo "line3"
echo -e "Test Message" | mutt -s "[E2E ]TestReport - Test Status" -- myemail@org.com
```

Now this one works once in a while. I receive an email in my mailbox with the From Name as `vsts@fv-az355-724.norxwxgvcn4uzhpoaxg0br3vlg.fx.internal.cloudapp.net`

Each time this email address is different.

I believe since my task is part of ci/cd pipeline, Each time deployment happens , this email is going to be auto-generated. My organization email system is somehow treating it as junk and not letting it enter everytime.

I also tried by editing the `~/.muttrc` file and setting the hostname.

Again it sent an email from that hostname only once and then it stopped. There are no errors or failures.

How can I solve this ?

Post Edit: while going through the logs, I came across following in the logs. The log is very long but this seems important. Mailutils is also installing postfix on its own.

```
Creating /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf
Adding group `postdrop' (GID 129) ...
Done.
setting myhostname: fv-az356-758.todi3lz1wlfenaxowbnpzhq2oe.fx.internal.cloudapp.net
setting alias maps
setting alias database
changing /etc/mailname to fv-az356-758.todi3lz1wlfenaxowbnpzhq2oe.fx.internal.cloudapp.net
setting myorigin
setting destinations: $myhostname, fv-az356-758.todi3lz1wlfenaxowbnpzhq2oe.fx.internal.cloudapp.net, localhost.todi3lz1wlfenaxowbnpzhq2oe.fx.internal.cloudapp.net, , localhost
setting relayhost: 
setting mynetworks: 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
setting mailbox_size_limit: 0
setting recipient_delimiter: +
setting inet_interfaces: all
setting inet_protocols: all
/etc/aliases does not exist, creating it.
WARNING: /etc/aliases exists, but does not have a root alias.
```

Is there a way I can change the myhostname and destinations in postfix so that my organization email does not treat this email id as spam and reject it silently?

Answer (score 0):

Not really answering your question directly, but offering a pointer that may provide a solution to the underlying issue.

`mutt` is either sending email directly to your organisation using its built-in SMTP handler, or it's passing the email to `postfix` on the same system and letting that send the message directly to your organisation.

One option here is to configure `mutt` to use Authenticated SMTP and deliver directly as a valid user within your organisation. You will need a username and associated password within your organisation for this, and you *really should not* use your own.

Reference: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/mutt#Native_SMTP_support

```
set my_pass = 'account really long and complex password'
set my_user = 'account name'

set realname = 'Account Real Name'
set from = account_email_address@your_organisation.com
set use_from = yes

set smtp_pass = $my_pass
set smtp_url = smtps://$my_user@your_organisation_smtp_server.com
set ssl_force_tls = yes
```

Obviously this isn't perfect, particularly as there is now a username/password combination embedded into your CI/CD pipeline, so work with your system administration and security people on this one. They might have alternative solutions, such as to whitelist an un-authenticated sender (from) address.